# How can we change or edit source code of the UI recorder?

Tags: node.js

I tried to change source code and edit it, but my changes are  reflected.

Also removing the UI recorder in my local machine didn't work.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: what can i do anything

Comment: I tried to change to start html page but changes not affect on ui recorder actually i removed start page but its show page which is already taken by ui recorder

Comment: how to edit this source code plz tell me

Comment: I tried to make sense out of your question, so please carefully review my changes. Then read [mcve] and enhance your question with more details. We really can't help you until you enable us to do so.

Comment: okk.. my UI recorder is working very well no issue in that but I want changes some code in that source code of UI recorder. I tried to some changes in start.html pages and create my simple html pages, but after changes code its not saved and display on browser last original start.html page of  UI recorder.so I want changes in start page (front page )of UI recorder